# Kendo UI multiple files upload issue

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor, kendo-upload

I am using a Kendo File Upload control to upload multiple files. Only few of the files are getting uploaded (especially first and last) or some random ones. Is there any solution for this ?

Index.cshtml :

```
<input name="files" id="files" type="file" multiple="multiple" />
```

JS File :

```
$("#files").kendoUpload
    ({
        async: {
            saveUrl: "/Controller/GetUserUploadedFiles",
            removeUrl: "/Controller/Remove",
            autoUpload: false,
            allowmultiple: true
        },
        select: function (e) {
            onSelect(e);
        },
        success: function (e) {
        },
        error: function (e) {
        }
    });
```

//Controller Method

```
[HttpPost]
   public void GetUserUploadedFiles(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
   {   
     //Custom logic here
   }
```

Also, it would be great if i can get all the files as Enumerable in one controller method call rather than having it called multiple times for multiple files.

Is there anything i am missing or doing wrong ?

Thanks,
Srini

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will upload all the files that were selected in Kendo Upload, and then run code on each.

```
[HttpPost]
public void GetUserUploadedFiles()
{   
    Request.Content.LoadIntoBufferAsync().Wait();
    var result = Task.Factory
                 .StartNew(() => Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync().Result,
                  CancellationToken.None,
                  TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning,
                  TaskScheduler.Default).Result;

    var contents = result.Contents;
    HttpContent httpContent = contents.First();        

    Stream file = httpContent.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result;

    if (file.CanRead)
    {
        // Code that will be executed on each file
    }
}
```

You can get the filename by using:

```
string filename = httpContent.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName.Replace("\"", string.Empty);
```

You can get the uploaded file media type by using:

```
string uploadedFileMediaType = httpContent.Headers.ContentType.MediaType;
```

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, the kendo batch option will only upload the files as a collection if selected at the same time (browse, then select more than one file). Once you select additional file(s) they will be sent in another request. The only way you can force the files to be posted during the same request is to use the synchronous mode rather than async. Good luck.

Comment: Yes, what you said is true for batch option.Anyways i do not need the batch upload, just tried it in case if it helps anyway. Modified my question without batch option. Thank you !

Comment: @Srini, I have tried both methods in a project that I have recently completed and if you want to retain the async option, then you can not avoid posting the files individually; the files will get posted one-by-one. The batch option does not work as expected and is rather useless.  I can post some code to explain what I have done to make the UI events as fluid as possible.